# The use of the word "extend" with the preposition "to" in context

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me if it is correct to use the preposition and the word together in the following sentence.

> Kate **extended** her hand **to** me to greet me.

I feel that the sentence sounds correct, but I doubt because I couldn't an example sentence with the word and preposition in dictionaries.

Comment: That works together well. It sounds good!

Comment: You won't always find an example of everything. There's nothing wrong with that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "extended" and "to" are good. While "to greet me" is an acceptable completion of the sentence, the correct version that goes with "extended" is "in greeting". One reason for that is that you've already established that "me" is the object of the sentence.

So: "Kate extended her hand to me **in greeting**."